# Upload file on firebase storage using the firebase admin sdk (java)

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to upload files using the firebase admin sdk for java. I followed this official guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start but when I upload I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: firebase-adminsdk-s5n1d@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have serviceusage.services.use access to the Google Cloud project.
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:227)
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:308)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:189)
at com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket.create(Bucket.java:987)

This sounds to me like I am not authorised, but according to the guide I should get an authenticated reference to the bucket...

This is the code:

```java
        FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                new FileInputStream("./XXX.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com")
                .setStorageBucket("[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        InputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        Blob blob = StorageClient.getInstance().bucket().create(fileName, file, Bucket.BlobWriteOption.userProject("[PROJECT_ID]"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found to problem:

You just have to remove the "Bucket.BlobWriteOption.userProject("[PROJECT_ID]")" Parameter.

Now it works fine.